# Convert MIPS assembly into hexadecimal

Tags: assembly, binary, hex, mips, instructions

I'm stuck trying to convert MIPS assembly into binary and by extension hexadecimal. The instruction I need to convert is bgtz as seen below.

```
loop:
    mul $v0, $v0, $a0
    addi $a0, $a0, -1
branch:
    bgtz $a0, loop #convert this line to hexadecimal
    jr $ra
```

I'm trying by converting into binary first but when converting into binary I know opcode is 000111 and I know rs is 00100 but I don't know what rt is as the loop confuses me.

Comment: `bgtz` doesn't use that instruction format. It is `0001 11ss sss0 0000 iiii iiii iiii iiii` where `i` is the distance to jump, in words.

Comment: What would be the distance to jump?

Comment: `loop-branch-1` PS: you can use an assembler to see for yourself.

Comment: brilliant, thanks. I'm gonna give it another go now :)